# Draw an Ellipse in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, ellipse

I'm trying to write a code to draw an ellipse in XNA. Suppose we have the following parameters:

1. Semi-major axis (a).
2. Semi-minor axis (b).
3. ellipse center (h,k).
4. and 2D rotation (theta).

How it possible to draw the ellipse using the above parameters.

Here is the function

```
public VertexPositionColor Set2dEllipse(int x, int y, int z, Color color)
{
    VertexPositionColor vertices= new VertexPositionColor[100];
    for(int i= 0;i<100;i++)
    {
        double angle = (i / 100 * Math.PI * 2);
        vertices[i].Position = New Vector3((x + (Math.Cos(angle)) * size.Width), (y + Math.Sin(angle) * size.Height), z);
        vertices[i].Color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please show some code so we can better help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified the code taken from [here](http://www.riemers.net/Forum/index.php?var=1282) to meet your requirements.

```
public void CreateEllipse(int a, int b, int h, int k, float theta)
{
    VertexPositionColor[] vertices = new VertexPositionColor[vertexCount];
    //Drawing an Ellipse with its major axis parallel to the x-axis. Rotation can be applied to change this.
    Vector3 position;
    const float max = MathHelper.Pi;
    //2 * max since we're moving from -Pi to +Pi in the loop.
    float step = 2 * max / (float)vertexCount;
    int i = 0;
    //Optional Axis and angle rotation for the ellipse (See later notes):
    //Vector3 axis = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
    float angle = MathHelper.ToRadians(theta);

    for (float t = -max; t <= max; t += step)
    {
        //Formula shamelessly taken from wikipedia
        position = new Vector3(h + a * (float)Math.Cos((double)t), k + b * (float)Math.Sin((double)t), 0f);
        //Optional Rotation for the Ellipse:
        //position = Vector3.Transform(position, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(axis, angle));
        vertices[i] = new VertexPositionColor(position, Color.DarkOrange);
        i++;
    }
    //Optional Rotation for the Ellipse:
    position = Vector3.Transform(position, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(axis, angle));
    //then add the first vector again so it's a complete loop (sounds familiar)
    position = new Vector3(h + a * (float)Math.Cos((double)-max), k + b * (float)Math.Sin((double)-max), 0f);
    vertices[vertexCount - 1] = new VertexPositionColor(position, Color.DarkOrange);

    vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, vertexCount * VertexPositionColor.SizeInBytes,
        BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
    vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(vertices);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But I got syntax error on the last line. `vertexCount * VertexPositionColor.SizeInBytes`. 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexPositionColor' does not contain a definition for 'SizeInBytes'. Any idea?

Comment: How were you using the `VertexPositionColor vertices` before? Just draw it with what you used for your method before, TBH I'm not sure...

Comment: This might help: http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/VertexBuffer_and_IndexBuffer.php

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the equation of the ellipse in terms of x or y alone. Then increment/decrement   x or y to get the other coordinate based on the direction . Here's what i did for a circle

```
 this.x+=1.5*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * direction;

 if(direction==1)
 {

     if(this.x>=(centerx+radius))
    {


        direction=-1;
    }

 }

 else
 {

     if(this.x<=(centerx-radius))
        {


            direction=1;
        } 
 }

    this.y=(  (float) Math.sqrt(Math.abs(((radius*radius)- ( (this.x -centerx )*    (this.x -centerx )) )) )*direction  +  centery )  ;
```

PS: the code is in java for libgdx. You can adapt accordingly